# Introduction to non linear parabolic differential equations.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, parabolic-pde

I would like to know what the basic references to study non-linear parabolic problems, specifically problems of the type

\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - \Delta u = f(x,u), 
\end{equation*}
with the standard boundary conditions.

What the main techniques to study the existence and qualitative results related to the above problem?

I know about Galerkin and semigroups methods in the context of linear equations, however I don't know examples of these and other methods applied in the non-linear case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a huge variety of techniques. For an introduction of some of them, try chapters 8 and 9 of Evans and chapter 14 of Taylor (located in volume 3)

Comment: Thanks for help @whpowell. I have a good background in variational and topological methods to get existence of elliptics PDEs  and a quick look in the chapters 8 and 9 of Evans, seems me that the methods used there are applied to elliptic differential equations.

Comment: Oh sorry I misread your question. Evans doesn't have much for semilinear parabolic equations iirc. However, I believe you will find what you are looking for in chapter 15 of Taylor. I would also recommend Terence Tao's lecture notes on inviscid fluid equations, particularly the lectures on Navier Stokes. I believe they are listed on his blog under the course listing 254A

Comment: If you like semigroups, then the lecture notes by Lunardi are the way to go https://www.math.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/~czaja/ISEM/08internetseminar200405.pdf.